# MySQL Load query getting slower

Tags: mysql

We have a  innodb table with 200 million data.we have scheduled  a load query which inserts around 15 million records daily.which takes nearly 3hrs to load these data.But now its taking nearly 15hrs to LOAD same  load query.
Is there any possible solution to overcome this issue.

```
load data infile '/NORTH1/partition/partition_2015-11-30.txt'  into table plugindb.mt_sms_log_backup
```

Comment: So what has changed in the meantime?

Comment: everything is same and we haven't changed any of the parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of heavy i/o's on the machine we have fine tuned some complex queries and now it got resolved.